# How can I host multiple Client WASM application in single Blazor project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm building ASP.NET Core Application hosting multiple Blazor WebAssembly apps.

My server's `Startup.cs`:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Notes.Web.Server
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.MapWhen(ctx => ctx.Request.Path.Equals("/client"), client =>
            {
                client.Use((ctx, nxt) =>
                {
                    ctx.Request.Path = "/client" + ctx.Request.Path;
                    return nxt();
                });
                
                client.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles("/client");
                client.UseStaticFiles();
                client.UseRouting();
                client.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                {
                    endpoints.MapControllers();
                    endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("/client/{*path:nonfile}", "client/index.html");
                });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

When I trying to reach `/client` address, page loading succesfully, but then the application does not load because script `_framework/blazor.webassembly.js` could not be found.

In client's `index.html` I have `<base href="/client/" />`
As you can see all stuff configured same as in the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

But it's dont works. Please help me. Thank you!

Comment: Debug (F12) the request, what is the URL in the failing request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change also your csproj adding this settings:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  ...
  <StaticWebAssetBasePath>FirstApp</StaticWebAssetBasePath>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\Client\{SOLUTION NAME}.Client.csproj" />
  <ProjectReference Include="..\SecondClient\SecondBlazorApp.Client.csproj" />
  <ProjectReference Include="..\Shared\{SOLUTION NAME}.Shared.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
```

read here for more information:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-5.0#hosted-deployment-with-multiple-blazor-webassembly-apps-1

### Example

This is an example of a working multiple Wasm application.
The following code is from my **Server** project in *Startup*:

```
app.MapWhen(ctx => ctx.Request.Host.Port == 5001 ||
            ctx.Request.Host.Equals("clientapp.com"), first =>
            {
                first.Use((ctx, nxt) =>
                {
                    ctx.Request.Path = "/Client" + ctx.Request.Path;
                    return nxt();
                });

                first.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles("/Client");
                first.UseStaticFiles();
                first.UseStaticFiles("/Client");
                first.UseRouting();

                first.UseAuthentication();
                first.UseAuthorization();

                first.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                {
                    endpoints.MapControllers();
                    endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("/Client/{*path:nonfile}",
                        "Client/index.html");
                });
            });
```

My Client.csproj contains:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">

<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <StaticWebAssetBasePath>Client</StaticWebAssetBasePath>
    <BlazorWebAssemblyLoadAllGlobalizationData>true</BlazorWebAssemblyLoadAllGlobalizationData>
  </PropertyGroup>
...
```

### Source code

Example of working project on GitHub https://github.com/nbiada/multiclient-wasm-example

Comment: I already do this thing, but it not works.

Comment: Browser cant load https://localhost:5001/Client/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js because its not found.

Comment: Alexsey I've added another piece of code. If you follow the Microsoft docs all works as expected.

Comment: I created an example project for you on GitHub. The link in the answer

Comment: thank you. I already resolve my problem. But I check your answer as right.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the `_framework/blazor.webassembly.js` to your host.cshtml?

Please check out this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/startup?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: I don't have any Host.cshtml. Instead of it i have index.html file

Comment: Yes, do you have the _framework/blazor.webassembly.js in there?

Comment: If not, you should add it in the body tag like: <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>

Comment: I already have <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script> but result the same.